# Using SharePoint's Enterprise Search webservice (search.asmx) and the Client Object Model side by side -- Different Document Titles

Tags: .net, sharepoint

I'm in the process of developing a Silverlight application that has the requirement of allowing the user to do a fulltext search of documents within a document library, which I'm using the search.asmx web service for. In addition, the user is allowed to search by certain metadata constraints.  For example, each document has a "Language" field in its list entry.  I am accomplishing this by running a recursive Caml Query on the document library.

Unfortunately, I am running into a bit of an issue: The title of the documents returned by the search.asmx file is the title of the actual document, where the title of the documents returned by the client object model is the contents of the "Title" field stored within the SharePoint list.  Is there any way to either have the client object model return the true Title of the document, or grab the value of all of the returned documents "Title" field from the sharepoint enterprise search web service?  I have searched and cannot find a way to do this yet.

Thank you.

search.asmx web service query packet example:

```
<QueryPacket>
    <Query>
     <Context>
        <QueryText type='MSSQLFT'>
            SELECT Name, Title, Path, Description, Write, Rank, Size FROM SCOPE() WHERE FREETEXT('something') AND CONTAINS(Path,'http://localhost/Lists/DocLibrary')
        </QueryText>
     </Context>
    </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

Client object model CamlQuery example:

```
<View Scope="Recursive">
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Language" />
        <Value Type="Text">English</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way will be to get the client object model to return the true "Title" field.

I think that your problem comes from the fact that columns in SharePoint have many names. Some are used in the UI (Display names), some are internal (Internal Name). When you are doing an SPQuery, you must use the internal name of the column if you want to be sure to get the right one (Internal names are unique, display names are not). The search.asmx web service will use one value, but the SPQuery will use another.

The "Title" column where "Title" is, as you have discovered, the internal name of the "Title" column in the SharePoint list. If you want to get another field, you need to find its internal name.

I recommend that you download and use [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/). It's a visual representation of the client object model. In this case, you can navigate to your document library, point to the field that you would like to get in your SPQuery and look at the "Internal Name" value for it. Do your SPQuery with that value if your FieldRef and i'm pretty sure you will get the results you are expecting.